# Query to add quarter condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario in which if the system date is between 1 to 5 of the current quarter the calculation should not include current quarter data and if it is greater than 5 it has to include all the data.

I am trying to include this condition in where clause but I am not able to acheive the result.

Could you please help me in this condition

```
SELECT 
     Dense_Rank() over(order by AMOUNT desc)as RANK,
     FISCAL,       
     AMOUNT
  FROM 
     T1 INNER JOIN  T2     ON 1=1
  WHERE ( FISCAL<( CASE WHEN t2.SYSDATE BETWEEN t2.CURRENTQUARTER_START_DATE  AND    ADD_DAYS(tw.CURRENTQUARTER_START_DATE,4)
                         THEN CURRENT_QUARTER                           
                         END ) OR (NULL)
```

I am not sure how to include that condition.

Comment: You usually want to subtract on the front: system date minus five days. It's possible that I don't quite understand your problem. How many rows are in `t2`?

Comment: Only one row is present where it has all the current quarter details like sysdate ,startdate,end date.
My problem is if the current date is between 1 to 5 of the current quarter I should not include data for this quarter else I should include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're after:

```
SELECT 
    Dense_Rank() over (order by AMOUNT desc) as RANK,
    FISCAL,       
    AMOUNT
FROM 
    T1
WHERE
    FISCAL <= (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN ADD_DAYS(SYSDATE, -5) >= CURRENTQUARTER_START_DATE
                THEN SYSDATE /* or maybe CURRENTQUARTER_END_DATE ? */
                ELSE ADD_DAYS(CURRENTQUARTER_START_DATE, -1)
            END
        FROM T2
    )
```

While you can do this with a join I think it makes sense to break it into logical pieces where the end-date lookup is isolated to a subquery and where the optimizer will understand that it should only see a single row/value.

Comment: I'm thinking you may want the `else` to subtract one day from start of current quarter. Make sure to check that it doesn't include too many days since I don't know whether you have dates or datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CASE
    WHEN t2.SYSDATE BETWEEN t2.CURRENT_QUARTER_START_DATE
        AND ADD_DAYS(tw.CURRENTQUARTER_START_DATE, 4)
    THEN CURRENT_QUARTER
    ELSE NULL
END
```